# Inferring type of tuple member

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

Is there a way to infer this chain of types in TypeScript? `infer` requires `extends` but I'm not able to use the tuple position to get a type for it.

```
type Step<I, O> = (i: I) => Promise<O>;

type Pipeline<I, O> = [Step<I, O>] | 
  [Step<I, infer M>, Step<M, O>] | 
  [Step<I, infer L>, ...Pipeline<L, infer R>, Step<R, O>];
```

`infer` is not valid due to that its not a conditional type.

In this case I want `Pipeline` to match arrays or (more precisely) tuples that are a set of functions that transform a given input type and produces the given output type, not caring about what intermediate values there are.

For instance, this pointless code should be satisfied.

```
const parseString: Step<string, number> = (str: string) => Promise.resolve(parseInt(str));
const toString: Step<number, string> = (int: number) => int.toString();

const flipFlop: Pipeline<string, number> = [parseString, toString, parseString];
```

Comment: you won't be able to use infer without extends anyway. Can you provide some test cases so that we can work on it?

Comment: @wonderflame yes exactly. ill add some matching runtime code

Comment: Hmm... This is something that (AFAIK) libraries like lodash currently limit typing for to a fixed number of pipeline elements, because the pipeline of each length has to be written out in full with extra type parameters. There _may_ be new features since then (I was looking into it about a year ago, I think) that enable this, but I couldn't say for certain.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8YO9N) work for you? If yes I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ideally, it would error on the mismatching types instead of resulting in `never`, but I think that's partly why some libraries decided to write it out explicitly (there have been a lack of the TS features required for your method, too).

Comment: I will see if I can do anything that would fire an error

Comment: There's no *specific* type that will work; you could write a constrained generic type as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqxDjN).  If that works for your needs I could write up an answer saying how it works, otherwise let me know what doesn't work about it.